# How to include js file from 'resources' folder (Laravel 5.5)

Tags: laravel-5

I used the following code to include my js file:

```php
Meta::addJs('admin_js', '/resources/assets/admin_js/admin_app.js');
```

The file exists but in the console I see status 404.

If I move the file to 'public' folder - all ok. But I want that this file be stored in 'resources' directory

Answer (score 10):

1. you have to move js files to `public` or store into `storage` and make symlinks.
2. or you need to create symlinks the `resources` directory to a `public` directory(which is not recommended).
3. you need to use the most recommended and effective method of Laravel of using Laravel mix. Please use the link below to read about laravel mix a solution.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix

It will allow you to place your `js` assets into `resources` directory and make compressed js file in `public` which will be used by the setup.

Answer (score 4):

Update for LARAVEL 7.0 :

Adding a vanilla JavaScript file to ‘resources’ :

1. Create the file in `resources/js` (called '**file.js**' in this example)
2. Go to `webpack.mix.js` file (at the bottom)
3. Add there: `mix.js('resources/js/file.js', 'public/js');`
4. Run in terminal : `npm run production`

Answer (score 3):

**Update for LARAVEL 9.0:**

Laravel now by default uses Vite instead of Mix

Adding a vanilla JavaScript file to ‘resources’ :

1. Create the file in resources/js (called 'file.js' in this example)
2. Go to vite.config.js file and add your filename to input

   ```
       input: [
           // rest of your inputs
           'resources/js/file.js',
       ],
   ```
3. Add reference to your `<head>`:

   ```
   <head>
       {{-- rest of your head --}}
       @vite('resources/js/file.js')
   </head>
   ```
4. Run `npm run dev` (run `npm install` if you haven't already)

More information can be found in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite).

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i am late but when i needed to load js file from directories and sub directories in my view file, i did this and it worked perfectly for me.
BTW i use laravel 5.7.

first of all i wrote a function that searched for any file in any given directory with this
.

```php
    /**
     * Search for file and return full path.
     *
     * @param  string  $pattern
     * @return array
     */
    function rglob($pattern, $flags = 0) {
        $files = glob($pattern, $flags);
        foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir) {
            $files = array_merge($files, rglob($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
        }
        return $files;
    }
```

the above will return a full path for each ".js" file in my "resources/view" directory.
Then i made a call to the above function to copy the content of each js to a single js file (new.js) which i created in my public/js using the below function.

```php
    /**
     * Load js file from each view subdirectory into public js.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function load_js_function(){
        //call to the previous function that returns all js files in view directory
        $files = rglob(resource_path('views').'/*/*.js');
        foreach($files as $file) {
            copy($file, base_path('public/js/new.js'));
        }
    }
```

After this i made call to the load_js_function() in my master blade layout(where i load all my css,js etc) immediately after loading the public/js/new.js, you can see below.

```html
      <script src="{!! asset('js/new.js') !!}"></script>
      <!-- load all js from each module -->
      {{ load_js_function() }}
```

These solution updates the file in public as you update the content of the original file.
Vote up if it works for you and comment if you have an issue implementing this, i will be glad to shed more light.
cheers