# How to mount riot tags inside a laravel project

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, riot.js

I need to add riot js to my laravel project and not sure I am doing the correct way to integrate riot for laravel project.

I have tried as follows in the blade.php file which is in the laravel views folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600"
        rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css"
    />
    <script src="../js/riotcompiler.js" type="riot/tag"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <hello></hello>
    <script src="../tags/hello.tag" type="tag"></script>
    <script>
        riot.mount("hello");
    </script>
    njk
</body>
</html>
```

Then when I run the laravel project it will generate an exception saying riot is not defined. But I have already installed riot globally. So how can I fix this issue? Do I need to install riot through composer?

Comment: Have you tried putting the riot script at the bottom of the body tag?

Comment: yes. same result

Comment: where did you put the riotcompiler.js? can you write the full path?

Comment: /blog/resources/js/riotcompiler.js

Comment: @DaFois that is the full path

Comment: refer to this answered question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49408259/how-to-include-js-file-from-resources-folder-laravel-5-5

Comment: I have moved the js file to the public folder and checked. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move js file to `public/js` folder you can call it in your blade file with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/riotcompiler.js') }}"></script>
```

The function `URL::asset()`will produce the necessary url for you.

Comment: now it is compiling riotcompiler.js. But a new error is appeared saying "Cannot read property 'class' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do the trick:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <title>Laravel</title>
      <!-- Fonts -->
      <link
         href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600"
         rel="stylesheet"
         type="text/css"
         />
      <script src="../js/riotcompiler.js" type="riot/tag"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <hello></hello>
      <script src="../tags/hello.tag" type="tag"></script>
      <script>
         riot.compile(function() {
         // here tags are compiled and riot.mount works synchronously
         riot.mount('hello')
         })

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: same result @GabMic. Still, riot is undefined

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not keeping tag files and riotcompiler file inside the public directory and not giving the path in a proper way in laravel. So the workable code is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Laravel</title>
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600"
        rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css"
    />
    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="{{ URL::asset('js/riotcompiler.js') }}"
    ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <hello></hello>
    <script
        src="{{ URL::asset('tags/hello.tag') }}"
        type="riot/tag"
    ></script>
    <script>
        riot.mount("hello");
    </script>
    njk
</body>
</html>
```